# How to calculate frequency with clock signal is 500ps in digital logic?

Tags: inverse

How can i calculate frequency if clock signal `500ps`.

I know the only formula, that is `T=1/f`

But i cant able to calculate, can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't $1000$ps $= 1$ns so that $500$ps$ = .5$ns. corresponding to a square wave of $2$Ghz?

Comment: $f = 1 / (500 ps) = 2 GHz$

Comment: Why is this question posted in maths SE? Would not the Signal Processing SE be more appropriate?

Comment: sorry, i am first time stackexcange.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1$ pico second (ps) is $1 \times 10^{-12}$ seconds, so if the time between pulses is $500$ps this is $500 \times 10^{-12}=5\times 10^{-10} $ seconds.

Then the frequency is $f=1/T=1/(5\times 10^{-10})=0.2 \times 10^{10}=2 \times 10^9=2 \rm{GHz}$